# Rails + Bootstrap: Font path not including base URI (production)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, passenger, glyphicons, bootstrap-sass

I'm using the bootstrap-sass gem and in production my rails app is deployed under a subfolder, i.e. the root is `http://www.example.com/sub/`. Everything works fine except for the fonts (particularly, Glyphicons): in the CSS the path to the font is this:

```
url("/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons...
```

when it should be

```
url("/sub/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons...
```

The CSS and JS assets all have the correct path, but the fonts don't. I've looked around the documentation (and the rest of the web) for a while but can't find how to change this--I'm a noob when it comes to the asset pipeline stuff.

I've got it deployed on Linux-Apache-Passenger.

Edit: I should add that I have this in my Apache site config:

```
Alias /sub /path/to/rails/app/public
<Location /sub>
    PassengerBaseURI /sub
    PassengerAppRoot /path/to/rails/app
</Location>
<Directory /path/to/rails/app/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here was the config option I needed in config/application.rb:

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/sub'
```

I would guess it's because the Apache/Passenger directive doesn't take effect when precompiling assets (e.g. the Bootstrap SASS) so you need to let the precompiler know where the fonts will be. Thanks for the help, wkaha and archie, and here's the ilnk on the bootstrap-sass github that clued me in: https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/issues/443

Comment: Hey! This worked for me. I had problems with the fonts' path.

Answer (score 1):

does this helps?

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

2.3.1 CSS and ERB

The asset pipeline automatically evaluates ERB. This means that if you add an erb extension to a CSS asset (for example, application.css.erb), then helpers like asset_path are available in your CSS rules:

```
.class { background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>) }
```

Comment: Not exactly, but section 5.4 talks about changing the assets path. Apparently this happens for the CSS and JS but not the fonts?

Comment: Use path_to_font instead of asset_path for font assets.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the reason.

[Bootstrap-sass gem precompiles the glyphicons](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/blob/544ad6c18af788582c62ef578587dcd0ae58b363/lib/bootstrap-sass/engine.rb)

config.assets.precompile << %r(bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.(?:eot|svg|ttf|woff)$)

Suggested workaround:

Copy the 4 glyphicon files into your assets pipeline and precompile in your own production or development config.